# Adobe media encoder encoding slow

Tags: after-effects, adobe-media-encoder

Help,
I have setup Adobe media encoder and After effects for cuda. My project is only 3,5 min long and my rendering time is about 2,5 hours. I have resized all my footage to match my resolution (1080p, 29,95 fps). I think this is strange because I have a decent graphics card. Here are my pc specs if it is going to help:

- Amd A6 cpu
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 960
- 8 GB ram
- Windows 10
- 3 2tb hard disks (about 1tb free for each drive)

I haven't changed any settings except the cuda renderer option.

Am I doing something wrong, is there something I can change in my settings to improve rendering time?

Please help.

Comment: Check the sequence and footage settings to make sure they match. If AE is doing frame interpolation to change frame rate, for example, that would slow it down.

Comment: @stib the settings are matching, maybe it has something todo with that I only have generated media and only 1 image

Comment: Well,  it could depend on the content of the composition,  things like motion blur and frame blending slow down renders considerably.

Comment: @stib I'm using trap code for an audio visualiser. Maybe that is the cause?

Comment: you could do a test render without it on to see if that's what it is. Just FYI a lot of AE rendering doesn't use the GPU, especially some of the older plugins, so CPU is the bottleneck.